# How to use one ChangeLog inside another in Liquibase?

Tags: liquibase

I have two `changeLog` which has `changeset`s to create two tables .

The changelog having changeset to create person

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

       <changeSet id="1" author="nvoxland">
        <createTable tableName="person">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="firstname" type="varchar(50)" />
            <column name="lastname" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="state" type="char(2)" />
            <column name="district" type="char(2)" />
            <column name="city" type="char(2)" />
         </createTable>
        </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

and the changelog to create passport

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

       <changeSet id="2" author="nvoxland">
        <createTable tableName="passport">
            <column name="passportNo" type="int">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
            </column>
         </createTable>
        </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

**I want to create a new changeset in a separate changelog which can use the above two changelog and add a foreignkey constraint between person and passport.**

Something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

       <changeSet id="3" author="nvoxland">
        import  changeset 1 & 2
        add foreign-key between person & passport 
        </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Is this possible using `Liquibase`? Please suggest the possible ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get your question right, you can use `master-changelog.xml` file and specify all your `changelog` files there.

Your `master-changelog` may look like this:

```
<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <include file="changelog/changelog_file_1.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="changelog/changelog_file_2.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="changelog/changelog_file_3.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

`changelog` files will be executed in the provided order, so the third `changelog` will already have all the needed data available.

So in your `changelog_file_3.xml` you'll have a `changeSet` with `<addForeignKeyConstraint>`.

By the way, you don't need to create separate `changelog` for each `changeset`.